# Микротик + NPS. Как собрать статистику о подключениях ВПН?

Tags: windows, vpn, статистика, mikrotik

Есть связка Микротик + Windows Radius (NPS) + AD.
Каким образом можно обработать статистику по впн-подключениям в какой-то наглядной форме?
Микрот пишет логи, я их собираю в mikrotik syslog daemon, но никак не могу найти чем обработать их потом.
На данный момент руками считаю потом в экселе, но это неудобно.
NPS тоже что-то пишет, но куда подключить его данные я найти не могу.
Задача проста - нужно получить общее время, которое человек провел со включенным ВПН. За сутки.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, самое простое решение.
Спасибо

Comment: в современном мире есть только один настраиваемый радиус сервер - freeradius... он развивается как бегемот, фишки добавляются через 5 лет как были нужны, развертывание ужасно, сетевой стек как из нулевых... но остальное ещё хуже) я пишу третий свой радиус сервер, но работать приходится с тем что есть.  посмотри в NPS есть настройка записи в sql, если нет, то фрирад на виртуалку в роли аккаунтинг бэкуп